Laravel: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages
Estoy aprendiendo laravel y siguiendo cursos, instale ya laravel composer y php pero al querer iniciar un proyecto nuevo me sale lo siguiente
PS C:\Users\santi\Desktop\Programacion\PHP\Laravel> laravel new relaciones

    Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./relaciones"
    Installing laravel/laravel (v11.1.3)
    Downloading laravel/laravel (v11.1.3)
    Installing laravel/laravel (v11.1.3): Extracting archive
    Created project in C:\Users\santi\Desktop\Programacion\PHP\Laravel/relaciones
    @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies

    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

    Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v11.9.0, ..., v11.15.0] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> 
      satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.28.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.15.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.28.0] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.28.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.15.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - league/flysystem-local[3.15.0, ..., 3.28.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^11.9 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v11.9.0, ..., v11.15.0].

    To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\php-8.3.9\php.ini
    You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.


Sí estas usando Wamp, Xampp, o Laragon, debes habilitar las extensiones de php en el php.ini, que es el archivo de configuración de php. debe de estar en las opciones de tu servidor de desarrollo, también es mejor que añadas el archivo composer, laravel y php al PATH de windows, a veces genera conflicto. Saludos espero lo resuelvas.
PHP >= 8.1

BCMath PHP Extension
Ctype PHP Extension
Fileinfo PHP extension
JSON PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension

(la versión de php es si estás usando laravel 10, eso puedes ignorarlo solo instala las externsiones)
